# Insert NEW RECORD to PostgreSQL Line by Line in C#

Tags: c#, postgresql, visual-studio-2012, vb6

Good day!

I am a newbie in **C#.NET** (I came from **VB6**).

I want to ***Insert*** new record to my database using **PostgreQL**.

I can use a single line of code, like:

```
Insert into table1 values("value1","value2","value3");
```

But I wanted to insert new record **line by line**, like:

```
rs.open("Select * from table1",con,AdOpenDynamic, AdLockOptimistic)
rs.Fields("Field1").value = value1    
rs.Fields("Field2").value = value2    
rs.Fields("Field3").value = value3    
rs.Update
```

Again, I am a newbie here. Also again, I can insert using a single **INSERT** statement.

But **IF** I have 40 Fields, the code is hard to read (for readability). If the code is line by line, it is easy to read and the code is easy to update.

Is there any way to do it? Any help will be appreciated!

Happy Coding!

Comment: The question is where is your record came from? even how may fields it is you don't have a choice except of specify the value for every designated field. You can search more on how to insert a record in your DB using Postgres

Comment: sir, do we have a workaround like `iDataSet.Tables[0].Rows[0]["stud_id"] = txtStudID.Text;`?
I want it to look like in vb6, line by line.

Comment: Forgot VB6 anymore.. You are working in the other environment now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks **@reds** for the Answer and suggestions. I realized my only problem is the code readability, not the code itself. As you have said, **Insert Query** is the best workaround. That's why I came up with the following structure:

```
////saving
        //CODE TO DATABASE
        NpgsqlConnection iConnect = new NpgsqlConnection("Server=localhost;Port=5432;User ID=postgres;Password=sdferekrjsdf873()#3s;Database=DB");
        iConnect.Open();
        NpgsqlCommand iQuery = new NpgsqlCommand
           ("insert into tblstudents_secure values('" + 
            myModule.studID + "','" + 
            myModule.studFname + "','" + 
            myModule.studMname + "','" + 
            myModule.studLname + "','" +
            myModule.studGrade + "','" +
            myModule.studSection + "','" + 
            myModule.studHomeAdd + "','" + 
            myModule.studProvAdd + "','" +
            myModule.studBday + "','" +
            myModule.studAge + "','" +
            myModule.studCivilStat + "','" +
            myModule.studHomeContact + "','" + 
            myModule.studProvContact + "','" + 
            myModule.studBplace + "','" +
            myModule.studGender + "','" +
            myModule.studReligion + "','" + 
            myModule.studFather + "','" + 
            myModule.studFatherOcc + "','" + 
            myModule.studMother + "','" + 
            myModule.studMotherOcc + "','" + 
            myModule.studGuardian + "','" + 
            myModule.studGuardianOcc + "','" + 
            myModule.studGuardianRel + "','" + 
            myModule.studGuardianContact + "','" + 
            myModule.studOldSchool + "','" + 
            myModule.studOldSchoolAdd  + "','" + 
            myModule.studOldGrade + "','" + 
            myModule.studOldSY + "','" + 
            myModule.studIsTransfer + "','" + 
            myModule.studHas137 + "','" + 
            myModule.studHas138 + "','" +
            myModule.studHasGoodMoral + "','" +
            myModule.studHasNSO + "','" + 
            myModule.studHasMed + "','" + 
            myModule.studRemarks + "','" +
            myModule.studDateRegistered + "','" +
            myModule.studEnrollmentStatus + "')", iConnect);

        iQuery.ExecuteNonQuery();
        iConnect.Close();
```

Where:
`

> myModule

is a class handler of `static` strings **studID**, **studFname**, etc...

Happy Coding!

Answer (score 1):

Even Postgres:

Code doesn't change it still

```
Insert into tablename(field1,field2,field3 and so on....) values(value1,value2,value3 and so on...)
```

Here's the workaround:

```
string connectionString = "Your connection string here";

protected static int ExecuteQuery(string query)
        {
            using (NpgsqlConnection con = new NpgsqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                con.Open();
                using (NpgsqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand())
                {
                    cmd.CommandText = query;
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    int result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    return result;
                }
            }
        }
```

To use this:

```
ExecuteQuery("Insert into tablename(field1,field2,field3 and so on....) values(value1,value2,value3 and so on...)")
```

Comment: But you have to be careful of naming convention in Postgres, do not use Upper Case field like Field1 because you are going use call this as select "Field1" in your query. But if you use lower case like field1 you can directly type this as select  field1 without double qoutes neede.